# Liferay Message Board thread by default view permission to user?

Tags: liferay

I want a message board thread by default visible for a role. No need to set permission each time thread is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by myself. All you have to do is create a Role and assign relevant users to that role. After this just add the required permission under " Define Permissions". then go for "Add Portlet Permission". Here, I have selected "Message Board" and given the required permission under it. I hope this will help any newbie to liferay. :)

Answer (score 0):

When i was working on liferay portal community edition. i did this using private page for each group.

```
There are two type of page for user 

1)Public pages
2)Private pages
```

I didn't found any other option for setting privileges for user.
I am sory, i can't tell you the exact name because worked an year ago.

Comment: I am able to make a page which is restricted for few roles only. But I  facing problem at thread level post only. If a group member post a thread then it will not allow other to view it until and unless administrator give the relevant privilege. I want thread should be visible to others by default.